# Android keyboard default request focus down not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Android keyboard default **`request focus`** down not working. Please check this images please anybody help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your layout.xml

Comment: a sample of your layout file would make it easy to find the problem

Comment: We could not know what is the problem by just looking at images you uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Place this in your layout: first editText
```

**android:imeOptions="actionNext"**

```
Last editText
```

**android:imeOptions="actionDone"**

Comment: Happy  Coding!! @Navaneethakrishnan